# Draw thin text with DrawString()?

Tags: c#, .net

I draw text on a picturebox with:

```
Point text_point = new Point(0, i);
Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
g.DrawString(Convert.ToString(i), drawFont, drawBrush, text_point);
```

... but the text is always drawn 'thick' like this:

**84**

How can I get it to look like: 84 ?

Comment: What about using a label instead?

Comment: Try `Font("Arial Narrow", 12, ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
```

Comment: This worked for me, not sure why this option is not set by default. I had a hard time figuring out why the fonts added via PrivateFontCollection where so thick when being rendered (like if they were bold), but this did the trick. Thanks for sharing